# Missing return in a function - swift error in Model

Tags: ios, swift, struct, model, compiler-errors

So I have self generated pie chart on the storyboard with various labels, sliders, buttons of Age, CurrentAsset, Income, etc. I'm building the model with struct and I keep getting errors for several methods that have "missing return in a function expected to return 'Double'" even though you can see that I have returns for currentAssetFactor, savingsFactor, bondFactor, toleranceFactor, outlookFactor. What am I doing wrong?

```
public struct AllocationModel
{
  let maxAge = 95.0
  let currentAge: Double

  let minCurrentAsset = 100000.0
  let maxCurrentAsset = 500000.0
  let currentAsset: Double

  let minSavings = 5000.0
  let maxSavings = 20000.0
  let currentSavings: Double

  let maxIncomeRequired = 0.04
  let minIncomeRequired = 0.01
  let currentIncomeRequired: Double

  let tolerance: String

  let outlook: String

  // MARK: - Methods

  public var currentAssetFactor: Double {
    if currentAsset > maxCurrentAsset {
      return 5.0
    } else if currentAsset >= minCurrentAsset {
      return Double(currentAsset / minCurrentAsset)
    }
  }

  public var savingsFactor: Double {
    if currentSavings >= maxSavings {
      return 4.0
    } else if currentSavings >= minSavings {
      return Double(currentSavings / minSavings)
    }
  }

  public var bondFactor: Double {
    if currentIncomeRequired >= maxIncomeRequired {
      return 0.2
    } else if currentIncomeRequired >= minIncomeRequired {
      return (0.05 * Double(currentIncomeRequired / minIncomeRequired) )
    }
  }

  public var toleranceFactor: Double {
    switch tolerance {
      case "conservative": return 0.0
      case "balanced": return 3.0
      case "aggressive": return 6.0
    default: 0.0
    }
  }

  public var outlookFactor: Double {
    switch outlook {
      case "poor": return 0.0
      case "moderate": return 7.0
      case "strong": return 10.0
    default: return 0.0
    }
  }


  public var stock: Double {
    return maxAge - currentAge + currentAssetFactor + savingsFactor + toleranceFactor + outlookFactor
  }

  public var nonStock: Double { return 100.0 - stock }

  public var bondPercentage: Double { return 0.35 + bondFactor }

  public var bond: Double { return nonStock * bondPercentage }

  public var cash: Double { return nonStock - bond }

  // MARK: - Init

  public init(currentAge: Double, currentAsset: Double, currentSavings: Double, currentIncomeRequired: Double, tolerance: String, outlook: String) {
    assert(currentAge > 0)

    self.currentAge = currentAge
    self.currentAsset = currentAsset
    self.currentSavings = currentSavings
    self.currentIncomeRequired = currentIncomeRequired
    self.tolerance = tolerance
    self.outlook = outlook
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not covering every case. Consider one of your methods:

```
  public var currentAssetFactor: Double {
    if currentAsset > maxCurrentAsset {
      return 5.0
    } else if currentAsset >= minCurrentAsset {
      return Double(currentAsset / minCurrentAsset)
    }
  }
```

Fine. So what if the first `if` fails (e.g. `currentAsset` is *not* greater than `maxCurrentAsset`) and the second `if` fails (e.g. `currentAsset` is *not* greater than or equal to `minCurrentAsset`)? Now we don't return anything!

So there's a hole in your logic. And the compiler is smart - smarter than you are! It is *so* smart that it spots this hole in your logic, and stops you in your tracks. You need to rewrite your methods in such a way as to *prove* to the compiler that every possibility is covered, i.e. that you will *always* return a value, no matter what.

Comment: You should look into writing this as a case statement ... it will help you catch missed cases

Comment: Adding to this answer, in the `outlookFactor` default: inside the switch you forgot the `return 0.0`

Comment: @Jeef what do you mean by a case statement for that "currentAssetFactor" example? I can only think of a Switch, but I'm not sure I can write for that specific example.

Comment: @matt. Thanks. You are right about a hole in my logic. I shouldn't have assume return 0.0 for else.